# VS2005 project has dependency that is not built

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, projects-and-solutions

I have VS2005 solution that contains many projects and dependencies (some C++, some C#) - in the past it compiled successfully.

when I rebuild all the solution it fails on a project claiming dll is missing (dll that was needed to built before according to dependency).

the thing is that from time to time it fails on random project (not all the time the same project).

I'm not sure it is meaningful but I see in output console 
**Deleting intermediate and output files for project**

doesn't VS2005 go according to "Project Build Order" and ReBuild every project starting with its dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably some project set to not build in the configuration manager of the solution, or maybe set to the wrong configuration.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Sebastiaan